# How can I create a power automate flow to delete folders in SharePoint with a certain size?

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, flow, power-automate

I am trying to find a way to create a flow that will delete folders in SharePoint but with a certain condition. I need the folders to be for example 10 KB or less in size. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample flow you can use to delete empty folders using the action “**Send an HTTP request to SharePoint**”: [How-To #4: Delete Empty Folders in SharePoint Document Libraries Using Power Automate.](https://faustocapellan.com/2020/11/30/how-to-4-delete-empty-folders-in-sharepoint-document-libraries-using-power-automate/)

If you want to add more conditions to the flow, modify the expression in the "**Filter array**" action in **Step 6** (click "Edit in advanced mode" to manually add expression).